# Cannot find view column in Google Analytic

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are using GA product. In our Admin board, we create a new account and a new property(web+App), but we don't see the view column. Since we want to use the google report api, the viewId is required, so we need to figure out how to create the views.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a former one.

Follow these steps.

1. Click the 'Show advanced option'
   [during the property creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8jds.png)

2. Activate the 'Create a Universal Analytics property'
   Check Also 'Create a Universal Analytics property Only'

Then you can see Tracking code and View.

Comment: No "after creating property" but "during the property creation"

Comment: that's right. edited .

Answer (score 11):

Only Universal Analytics property has ViewID. GA4 has not.

Admin > Create Property > Show Advance Option
[image]

Comment: How do you get here?

Comment: It is a option when you create new property.
Admin > Create Property > Show Advance Option

Answer (score -1):

new property(app+web) doesn't provide any 'view's. And i think the thing 'the viewid' meant 'measurement id' in new property.
maybe below posts from Krista would be helpful to deal with your problem

https://www.kristaseiden.com/step-by-step-setting-up-an-app-web-config-tag-in-gtm/

Comment: It's not right. ViewID is not 'measurement id'

Comment: This answer is very hard to understand